# C# removing XML parent nodes remains empty nodes

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am going to implement on removing the parent nodes but when it runs again , the Exception occurs and seems to be the Parsing error

The below is my original xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <stock>
     <brand name="Samsung">
         <product name="Galaxy S2"/>
         <product name="Galaxy S3"/>
         <product name="Galaxy S4"/>
     </brand>      
     <brand name="iPhone">
         <product name="iPhone 4"/>
         <product name="iPhone 5"/>
     </brand>
 </stock>
```

My target is to do this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<stock>
    <brand name="Samsung">
        <product name="Galaxy S2"/>
        <product name="Galaxy S3"/>
        <product name="Galaxy S4"/>
    </brand> 
</stock>
```

The below is my result of delete using RemoveAll();

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<stock>
   <brand name="Samsung">
      <product name="Galaxy S2"/>
      <product name="Galaxy S3"/>
      <product name="Galaxy S4"/>
  </brand>
  <brand/>
</stock>
```

The below is my code

```
public bool deleteBrand(string brand)
{
    bool result = false;

    try
    {
        List<string> existingBrandName = getBrand();
        if (existingBrandName.Contains(brand))
        {
            XDocument productList = load();

            var query = from positions in productList.Descendants("brand")
                        where (string)positions.Attribute("name").Value == brand
                        select positions;

            XElement selectedBrand = query.ElementAt(0);
            selectedBrand.RemoveAll();


            var emptyElements = from element in productList.Descendants("stock")
                                where element.IsEmpty
                                select element;

            while (emptyElements.Any())
                emptyElements.Remove();

            productList.Save(path);
            result = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }


    return result;
}
```

Comment: I don't see the difference: the expected and the result look the same. ???

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do - and you've made it less clear than it would have been by not indenting your XML properly. Are you just trying to remove all brand elements other than the first one? Please *describe* what you're trying to achieve, really clearly.

Comment: @JonSkeet I just reindented the XML.

Comment: When I run the code to delete another node again , it causes XML parsing error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the `emptyElements` thing with `brand` as well:

```
public bool deleteBrand(string brand)
{
    bool result = false;
    try
    {
        List<string> existingBrandName = getBrand();
        if (existingBrandName.Contains(brand))
        {
            XDocument productList = load();
            var query = from positions in productList.Descendants("brand")
                        where (string)positions.Attribute("name").Value == brand
                        select positions;
            XElement selectedBrand = query.ElementAt(0);
            selectedBrand.RemoveAll();
            var toCheck = productList.Descendants("stock")
                                     .Concat(productList.Descendants("brand"));
            var emptyElements = from element in toCheck
                                where element.IsEmpty
                                select element;
            while (emptyElements.Any())
                emptyElements.Remove();
            productList.Save(path);
            result = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Would you please tell me what is the use or purpose to combine the list of "stock" , and "brand" ?

Comment: @RajuGujarati You can remove them both, so then it gets rid of the useless `<brand/>` that seemed to be your only problem.

Comment: What list do I have to concat if I want to delete the product shown in the xml ?

Comment: @RajuGujarati Sorry, what do you mean?